Error: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification
I am using the Python sdk for firebase functions.
When I try to deploy functions by running the command firebase deploy I receive this Error

Error: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

I get the same error when running firebase function emulator,
If I run the command firebase init functions and reinstall all the dependencies, the error stops occurring, but reappears if I stop the emulators and run them again.
I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the dependencies and run firebase deploy, but the error persists.
I ran the command firebase deploy --debug to get logs, here are the logs
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.722Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.724Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (hahmed.1015@gmail.com)
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.724Z] [iam] checking project prizebonds-16d6e for permissions ["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","datastore.indexes.create","datastore.indexes.delete","datastore.indexes.list","datastore.indexes.update","firebase.projects.get","firebasedatabase.instances.update"]
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.727Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:testIamPermissions [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.727Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:testIamPermissions x-goog-quota-user=projects/prizebonds-16d6e
[2024-04-20T02:02:14.728Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","datastore.indexes.create","datastore.indexes.delete","datastore.indexes.list","datastore.indexes.update","firebase.projects.get","firebasedatabase.instances.update"]}
[2024-04-20T02:02:16.117Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:testIamPermissions 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:16.118Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","datastore.indexes.create","datastore.indexes.delete","datastore.indexes.list","datastore.indexes.update","firebase.projects.get","firebasedatabase.instances.update"]}
[2024-04-20T02:02:16.119Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/serviceAccounts/prizebonds-16d6e@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:testIamPermissions [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:16.119Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/serviceAccounts/prizebonds-16d6e@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["iam.serviceAccounts.actAs"]}
[2024-04-20T02:02:17.553Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/serviceAccounts/prizebonds-16d6e@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:testIamPermissions 404
[2024-04-20T02:02:17.554Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/serviceAccounts/prizebonds-16d6e@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:testIamPermissions {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Unknown service account","status":"NOT_FOUND"}}
[2024-04-20T02:02:17.554Z] [functions] service account IAM check errored, deploy may fail: HTTP Error: 404, Unknown service account {"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"context":{"body":{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Unknown service account","status":"NOT_FOUND"}},"response":{"statusCode":404}},"exit":1,"message":"HTTP Error: 404, Unknown service account","status":404}
[2024-04-20T02:02:17.556Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:18.070Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:18.071Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e {"projectId":"prizebonds-16d6e","projectNumber":"784905849810","displayName":"prizeBonds","name":"projects/prizebonds-16d6e","resources":{"hostingSite":"prizebonds-16d6e","realtimeDatabaseInstance":"prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_3927acd3-cf07-48a5-a957-d6f4deccae90"}

=== Deploying to 'prizebonds-16d6e'...

i  deploying database, firestore, functions
i  database: checking rules syntax...
[2024-04-20T02:02:18.078Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/locations/-/instances/prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:19.598Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/locations/-/instances/prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:19.598Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/locations/-/instances/prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb {"name":"projects/784905849810/locations/us-central1/instances/prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb","project":"projects/784905849810","databaseUrl":"https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com","type":"DEFAULT_DATABASE","state":"ACTIVE"}
[2024-04-20T02:02:19.600Z] >>> [apiv2][query] PUT https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json dryRun=true
[2024-04-20T02:02:19.600Z] >>> [apiv2][body] PUT https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json "{\n  \"rules\": {\n    \".read\": false,\n    \".write\": false\n  }\n}"
[2024-04-20T02:02:20.289Z] <<< [apiv2][status] PUT https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:20.290Z] <<< [apiv2][body] PUT https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json {"status":"ok"}
+  database: rules syntax for database prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb is valid
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
[2024-04-20T02:02:20.300Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:test [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:20.300Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:test [omitted]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.343Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:test 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.343Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e:test {}
+  cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.344Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.856Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.857Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e {"projectId":"prizebonds-16d6e","projectNumber":"784905849810","displayName":"prizeBonds","name":"projects/prizebonds-16d6e","resources":{"hostingSite":"prizebonds-16d6e","realtimeDatabaseInstance":"prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_3927acd3-cf07-48a5-a957-d6f4deccae90"}
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.859Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.859Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com x-goog-quota-user=projects/prizebonds-16d6e     
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.860Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.861Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com x-goog-quota-user=projects/prizebonds-16d6e      
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.862Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.862Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com x-goog-quota-user=projects/prizebonds-16d6e
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.863Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/artifactregistry.googleapis.com [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:21.864Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/artifactregistry.googleapis.com x-goog-quota-user=projects/prizebonds-16d6e   
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.505Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.505Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com [omitted]
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.506Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.506Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com [omitted]
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.528Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.529Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com [omitted]
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.532Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/artifactregistry.googleapis.com 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.533Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/services/artifactregistry.googleapis.com [omitted]
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
[2024-04-20T02:02:23.533Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/adminSdkConfig [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.038Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/adminSdkConfig 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.038Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/adminSdkConfig {"projectId":"prizebonds-16d6e","databaseURL":"https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com","storageBucket":"prizebonds-16d6e.appspot.com"}
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.039Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/configs [none]
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.676Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/configs 200
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.676Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/prizebonds-16d6e/configs {}
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.678Z] Customer code is not Node
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.679Z] Validating python source
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.679Z] Building python source
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.681Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.689Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="G:\My Drive\dev\firebase\new\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","python.exe","-c","\"import firebase_functions; import os; print(os.path.dirname(firebase_functions.__file__))\""]
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.915Z] stdout: G:\My Drive\dev\firebase\new\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\firebase_functions

[2024-04-20T02:02:24.924Z] Running admin server with args: ["python.exe","\"G:\\My Drive\\dev\\firebase\\new\\functions\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\firebase_functions\\private\\serving.py\""] and env: {"FIREBASE_CONFIG":"{\"projectId\":\"prizebonds-16d6e\",\"databaseURL\":\"https://prizebonds-16d6e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"prizebonds-16d6e.appspot.com\"}","GCLOUD_PROJECT":"prizebonds-16d6e","GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT":"prizebonds-16d6e","ADMIN_PORT":"8081"} in G:\My Drive\dev\firebase\new\functions
[2024-04-20T02:02:24.924Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="G:\My Drive\dev\firebase\new\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","python.exe","\"G:\\My Drive\\dev\\firebase\\new\\functions\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\firebase_functions\\private\\serving.py\""]
 * Serving Flask app 'serving'
 * Debug mode: off

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8081

Press CTRL+C to quit

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2024 07:02:34] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -


Error: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Please edit the question to show what you are trying to deploy.  We need a complete minimal reproducible example, which includes everything in a project that fails this way. There should be enough information in your question that anyone can use to reproduce this error.

Same error here. Have you fixed it?

First of all, cloud function in combination with firebase is really not ready for production use, at best this is an early alpha level feature (at least for Python code). That being said and warned about, this is likely caused by something that raises an error in the code when it is scanned. For me it was the module level setup of the firestore db, which has to go into the functions to not be called during the deployment stages. Only trial and error of your code, line by line, will reveal what breaks the deployment, thanks to Google's amazing debug functionality here (/s)
